# How to invoke methods on the same singleton object in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, singleton, cx-oracle

```
from __future__ import annotations
import cx_Oracle as oracle

class Connection(oracle.Connection):
        __connection = None
    
        @classmethod
        def create(cls) -> Connection:
            """Returns a singleton cx_Oracle.Connection object."""
    
            if not cls.__connection:            
                cls.__connection = oracle.connect(
                    user="xxx",
                    password="xxx",
                    dsn="xxx",
                    mode=oracle.SYSDBA
                )
    
            return cls.__connection
```

I want to use a singleton database connection object in my project to avoid creating a connection more than one. In this example `oracle.connection` method returns the instance of the parent class.(which is `cx_Oracle.Connection`)

My question is how can i return `Connection` instance (which is the class i created) instead of `cx_Oracle.Connection` class. Because I want to invoke some methods on my singleton object like;

```
connection = Connection.create()
connection.execute()
```

Only my `Connection` class will have `execute` method, not the parent class.

Comment: Instead of a singleton, can you create a connection pool (`cx_Oracle.SessionPool()`) with maximum of one connection? Then do an `acquire()` and `close()` when you use the connection.   The advantage is that the connection pool can recreate the connection if the network drops out, and the pool supports some other Oracle high availability features.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound obvious but in order to return an instance, you must first create one - and you don't. So do that and return it:

```py
        @classmethod
        def create(cls) -> Connection:
            """ Sets up a database connection if needed and returns
                a new Connection instance.
            """
    
            if not cls.__connection:            
                cls.__connection = oracle.connect(
                    user="xxx",
                    password="xxx",
                    dsn="xxx",
                    mode=oracle.SYSDBA
                )
    
            instance = Connection()
            return instance
```

Just make sure these instances use the class property `__connection` whenever they query the database.